# Is there another word instead of 'dilute'?

Tags: word-choice

Is there another word instead of "dilute" for this context:

> XXX production was carried out by ***diluting*** XOXOXO fertilizer.

Comment: Need more context. If said "production" was simply "adding water" to fertilizer, then diluting is the proper word.

Comment: @lurker: the liquid amount of XOXOXO fertilizer can be increased by **diluting** it.?

Comment: Water is substance and substance has volume, so yes, adding volume to fertilizer makes MORE fertilizer.

Comment: @lurker  Sprinkle salt in a glass.  Pour in water.  You have not created any more salt.

Comment: "thinning" might work.

Comment: @EuanM: but it will work different when you put xoxoxo fertilizer then adding it with 10% of water.

Answer (score 2):

> XXX production was carried out by reducing the **concentration** of XOXOXO fertilizer.

or

> XXX production was carried out by reducing the **strength** of XOXOXO fertilizer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the verb "thin" or "thin down" instead of "dilute."

"Thin" as a transitive verb can be used in the sense of making something thinner or less thick by adding water or another liquid to it.

Answer (score 1):

When you're using a term to express reduction in strength by adding water (for favorable conditions), **'diluting'** is your best bet. Furthermore, you could add **'adulterating'** if the context is for an unfavorable event.

- **Dilute the milk** - 
  *Add water to the milk intentionally.*
- **I was given adulterated milk** - *Producer has added water to pure , with intentions to make a profit.*

Answer (score 1):

"watering down" would work, although only appropriate if a liquid is used, and ideally water.
"cutting" is used in the context of things like recreational drugs mixed with cheaper substances to increase the amount available for sale (with less potency, of course). Usually explicit, eg "the heroin we found was cut with icing sugar..."